# Searching Multiple Strings in Huge log files

Tags: windows, string, powershell, full-text-search

Powershell question

Currently i have 5-10 log files all about 20-25GB each and need to search through each of them  to check if any of 900 different search parameters match. i have written a basic powershell script that will search through the whole log file for 1 search parameter. if it matches it will dump out the results into a seperate text file, the problem is it is pretty slow. i was wondering if there is a way to speed this up by either making it search for all 900 parameters at once and only looking through the log once. any help would be good even if its just improving the script.

basic overview :

1 csv file with all the 900 items listed under an "item" column
1 log file (.txt)
1 result file (.txt)
1 ps1 file

here is the code i have below for powershell in a PS1 file:

```
$search = filepath to csv file<br>
$log = "filepath to log file"<br>
$result = "file path to result text file"<br>
$list = import-csv $search <br>


foreach ($address in $list) {<br>
Get-Content $log | Select-String $address.item | add-content $result <br>

*"#"below is just for displaying a rudimentary counter of how far through searching it is <br>*
$i = $i + 1 <br>
echo $i <br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

900 search terms is quite large a group. Can you reduce its size by using regular expressions? A trivial solution is based on reading the file row-by-row and looking for matches. Set up a collection that contains regexps or literal strings for search terms. Like so,

```
$terms = @("Keyword[12]", "KeywordA", "KeyphraseOne") # Array of regexps
$src = "path-to-some-huge-file" # Path to the file
$reader = new-object IO.StreamReader($src) # Stream reader to file

while(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null){ # Read one row at a time

    foreach($t in $terms) { # For each search term...
        if($line -match $t) { # check if the line read is a match...
            $("Hit: {0} ({1})" -f $line, $t) # and print match
        }
    }
}
$reader.Close() # Close the reader
```

Comment: I agree. Shrinking the number of search terms would help alot if possible. The use of StreamReader will reduce the time a lot on it's own. Have you considered using `Select-String -Pattern $terms` to match instead? It takes an array as pattern-input. Not sure how performance is compared to foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is going to be incredibly painful on any parser you use just based on the file sizes you have there, but if your log files are of a format that is standard (for example IIS log files) then you could consider using a Log parsing app such as Log Parser Studio instead of Powershell?